# Is the ubuntu a VM instance if I choose to install it alongside with windows via the wubi installer?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, wubi, linux-kvm

I recently installed a Ubuntu 12.10 64bit using wubi installer under Windows 8. Every time I start my machine, it will go to the Windows 8 bootloader first and then I can choose which operating system I want.

After I choose ubuntu, the machine will actually start again(go through the bios screen), and then get into the GNU GRUB.

My question is that, after I choose ubuntu in GNU GRUB, I'm in the process of booting up my ubuntu system. However, during this process, I always see a message that shows up in the screen saying

> "KVM: disabled by bios"

I googled this message and everything I found was that I need to enable the Intel Virtualization Technology(I have an i5 CPU) in my bios.

I haven't tried to enable the VT feature to see what will happen when ubuntu boots up. But I have a question in my mind: **Why do I need the VT for ubuntu?? Is the ubuntu I installed via wubi installer under Window 8 a VM instance?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely ignore this message.

You don't need the VT feature for Ubuntu.  You only need the VT feature if you are wanting Ubuntu to act as a VM Server, ie to use it as a host for virtual machines (for example using KVM).  If you are just wanting to use it as a regular server or even a virtual client you don't need to enable VT in your BIOS.

The message you are getting, I believe, comes from the Linux Kernel where parts of the code required for running KVM are disabled because your BIOS is not set to allow your processor to handle it.

If you are using GRUB to Boot into Windows or Ubuntu, you are not running Ubuntu in a VM.  (When you are running a VM, you load 1 OS, then fire up a virtual server from that server.  With Grub you are selecting which OS to use before the OS is loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Wubi will install it directly on your hard drive, and you will be able to boot it up instead of Windows. Once finished, you can reboot and boot Windows again.